# CSS being overridden by browser defaults

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where my CSS code is being ignored. From the DOM it appears to be due to my selectors being overridden by browser default: *-webkit- selectors 'user agent stylesheet'*. I don't have any duplicate selectors so the issue isn't similar selectors overriding each other.

My code snippets are attached. Any ideas why my selectors aren't working? And I thought the order of the CSS code didn't matter unless there are duplicate selectors? FYI, I was using a `normalize.css` with my project, but I didn't include that for simplicity.

```css
<!--====================================
      NAV/COVER SECTION
======================================-->

.coverHomeLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.navbarButton {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}

.navbarFlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbarMenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.navbarMenu a {
  align-self: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background-color: #3e465b;
  border-color: #ecc445;
  border-style: none;
  width: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbarMenu a:hover {
  color: #ecc445;
}

.mainTitle {
  padding: 180px 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
}

.coverContainer {
  padding: 20px;
/*  position: relative;*/
  background: linear-gradient(105deg, #3e465b 55%, #ecc445 250%);
}


<!--====================================
      WORK SECTION
======================================-->

.workSection {
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

.workProject {
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.projectImage {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
  border-top-left-radius: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}

.visitWebsiteButton {
  padding: 12px 18px;
  background-color: #ecc445;
  border-color: #ecc445;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
}


<!--====================================
      FOOTER  
======================================-->

footer {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #3e465b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:800|Archivo+Black|Questrial|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>My Name | Work</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    
<!--====================================
      NAV/COVER SECTION
======================================-->

    
    <div class="coverContainer">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbarFlexContainer">
          <a href="#" id="test" class="coverHomeLink">My Name</a>
          <button href="#" class="navbarButton"><img src="img/navbarImage.svg"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbarMenu">
          <a href="#" style="color:#ecc445">Work</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <div class="mainTitle">
        <h1 class=""><span>&times;</span> Text Here.... <span>&times;</span></h1>
        <h2>Insert tag line here, to be determined...</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    
<!--====================================
      WORK SECTION
======================================-->
    
    <div class="workSection"> <!-- Work Section -->
    
      <div class="workProject">
        <div class="projectImage">
          <h3>Project Name</h3>
        </div>
        <p>
          <a href="#project1About" class="aboutProjectLink">About Project</a>

          <button href="#" class="visitWebsiteButton">Visit Website</button>
        </p>
        <div id="project1About" class="aboutProjectDiv">
          <p>fkldsjjffkdls fdjsjfkds uri. jfdksajfjdsjfl;kdjs. jfkdsjfljjsd.</p>
          <p>fkldsjjffkdls fdjsjfkds uriewuriwe fdjksljndkl f djskfjd jfdk jfkdsjkfd kfjdfkdjflkjdk fjdjf kdjkfjdkfjdkf jdkfjdkfjkdfjklj . fkjkdjkjeijeifjijeijeijeijeijc ije jeke knkcdknckdkcndjkncdjcndjncjkdnl fjdksjfl jkfdls dkjcnkeijiejijfkds jiefjifehfe.</p>
          <p>fkldsjjffkdls fdjsjfkds uriewuriwe fdjksljndkl f djskfjd jfdk jfkdsjkfd kfjdfkdjflkjdk fjdjf kdjkfjdkfjdkf jdkfjdkfjkdfjklj . fkjkdjkjeijeifjijeijeijeijeijc ijefehfe.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  <!-- /Work Section -->
    
<!--====================================
      FOOTER  
======================================-->
    <footer>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Work</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>
      
<!--====================================
      SCRIPTS
======================================-->
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: css snippets are evaluated from top to bottom so if you have multiple styles defined for any element, the latter one would take precedence and be applied

Comment: The order absolutely matters. When given two selectors with identical specificity, the last one is given precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the *computed styles* portion of the *DOM Inspector* of the browser's Web Developer tools?

In Waterfox (and Firefox) after choosing an element in the *Inspector* on the right panel click on the *Computed* tab. A right-pointing arrow when clicked will display which styles are applied and which aren't.

You do realize that CSS stands for *Cascading* Style Sheets right?

```
h1 {float: left;}
h1 {float: none;}
```

The `h1` element will *not* `float` because the second definition sets it to *not* `float`. Work on your understanding of CSS and you'll get it.

Comment: Side note, "Cascading" has nothing to do with this. That's how certain styles are inherited by children.

Comment: I'm aware of how CSS works in terms of overriding properties that come later in the CSS file for the same selector (as you've shown with the h1 float example), and that's why I'm stumped because I don't have any selectors for the same element causing overrides. In the DOM I'm being overridden by -webkit- selectors 'user agent stylesheet' which I assume is the browser default settings. But other elements (such as my footer selector) isn't even showing up in the DOM even though I've set properties to it in my CSS.

Comment: Look at my profile, find a CSS related question, reformat your question to more concise (instead of posting all of the code) and reply again and I will be happy to help you out. Oh, I see your self-answer...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my was using `html` comment markers in my `css`, such as `<!-- NAV SECTION -->`, rather than the proper `css` comment markers like this `/* NAV SECTION */`, which buggered up my documents.

Comment: Yeah, CSS comments use `/* this */` for comments and unlike JavaScript there are no single line comments (`//comment`).